# VueJS position multiple children with canvas components inside parent

Tags: css, vue.js, canvas, html5-canvas, positioning

I have multiple components that essentially are simply canvas elements with event listeners for interactivity.

I have set the height and width of the canvas elements via JavaScript inside each component (if each component is rendered to the screen on its own, it will take up the full viewport).  Note that each child component has one or more canvas elements with `position: absolute` inside a div with `position: absolute`.

I would like to have a parent component that can display these canvas children on different parts of the screen, for which a CSS grid layout came to mind. However, I cannot figure out how to get the canvas elements to display correctly.

If I simply insert them one after another in the parent component, they render on top of one another due to the parent being `position: static` by default. If I wrap each child in a div with `position: relative` the display is not as expected.

Is it possible to wrap these children to take up 100% of allotted screen space allocated by the parent? That is, each child will be granted a portion of the screen, for which it will take up 100% of that space, without overlapping a sibling?

Example:
child Canvas component 1 (ArrangeWindow.vue):

```
<template>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="arrangeCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    let arrangeCanvas = document.getElementById("arrangeCanvas");
    let arrangeCtx = arrangeCanvas.getContext("2d");

    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let dpi = window.devicePixelRatio;
    let height = container.clientHeight * dpi;
    let width = container.clientWidth * dpi;

    arrangeCanvas.setAttribute("height", height);
    arrangeCanvas.setAttribute("width", width);

    arrangeCtx.beginPath();
    arrangeCtx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
    arrangeCtx.fillStyle = "#666699";
    arrangeCtx.fill();
  }
};
</script>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#arrangeCanvas {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

child canvas Component 2 (named YellowCanvasTest.vue)

```
<template>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="arrangeCanvas2"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    let arrangeCanvas2 = document.getElementById("arrangeCanvas");
    let arrangeCtx = arrangeCanvas.getContext("2d");

    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let dpi = window.devicePixelRatio;
    let height = container.clientHeight * dpi;
    let width = container.clientWidth * dpi;

    arrangeCanvas2.setAttribute("height", height);
    arrangeCanvas2.setAttribute("width", width);

    arrangeCtx.beginPath();
    arrangeCtx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
    arrangeCtx.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
    arrangeCtx.fill();
  }
};
</script>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#arrangeCanvas2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

parent Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
    <div class="container">
      <arrange-window></arrange-window>
    </div>
    <div class=“container”>
      <yellow></yellow>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ArrangeWindow from "../components/ArrangeWindow";
import yellow from '../components/YellowCanvasTest'
export default {
  components: {
    arrangeWindow: ArrangeWindow,
    yellow
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Note what happens when `.container` has its position changed to relative.  Also note what happens when the css for .container is removed entirely.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem, because recreating your described state and trying to find as well as test a suitable solution takes too much time.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß yes certainly; I apologize I was typing the question from my phone but will do so ASAP.

Comment: are you talking about html `canvas[width,height]` attrs or about css `canvas[style="width: 100px"]`, when you have the first one correct, it should be as simple as `style=width:100%` or similar

Comment: @birdspider I've updated the question with an example. I couldn't figure out how to make the example on codepen since I need to do some lifecycle hooks and things that wouldn't fit inline (without looking terrible)."

Comment: @ConstantinGroß updated with code that can be copied and run and reproduces the issue.  Note that when the code is run, the yellow canvas is visible but the purple one is not (it is rendered beneath the yellow canvas).